# Unix network programming /socket programming

Tags: unix-socket

I get the following error

In function `w_Endline`:

```
/home/prog2/in_out.c:113:19: error: assignment of read-only l       ocation ‘*(sent + (sizetype)(endlen * 1ul))’
       sent[endlen]='\0';


/home/prog2/in_out.c: In function ‘w_White’:
/home/prog2/in_out.c:119:19: warning: initialization discards        ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
      char* endlen=sent+whitelen;

/home/prog2/in_out.c:120:6: warning: implicit declaration of        function ‘isspace’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      while(endlen>sent &&isspace(*endlen))
```

FILES

1.in_out.c http://ideone.com/nI15F4

```
void w_Endline(const char* sent)
{
  size_t endlen=strlen(sent)-1;
  if(sent[endlen]=='\n')
  sent[endlen]='\0';
}
void w_White(const char* sent)
{
  size_t whitelen=strlen(sent);
  char* endlen=sent+whitelen;
  while(endlen>sent &&isspace(*endlen))
  {
    endlen='\0';
    --endlen;
  }
}
```

2.in_out.h http://ideone.com/lDxxhY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use const in `w_Endline` if you are modifying the pointer also you need `ctype.h` header for `isspace()` function. Also in `w_White` function if you are assigning a const pointer the pointer also needs to be const.

```
 char* endlen=sent+whitelen;
```

should be

```
const char* endlen=sent+whitelen;// because sent is const
```

Actually const qualifier means read-only

Comment: Well that has fixed the issue with in_out 
But i get error in other file name query.c
3.query.c  http://ideone.com/uXzoLc
4.query.h http://ideone.com/umPmWO

Comment: query.c: In function ‘doQuery’:
query.c:40:15: error: passing argument 1 of ‘w_Endline’ discards ‘const’ qualifi           er from pointer target type [-Werror]
     w_Endline(title);
               ^
In file included from query.c:27:0:
in_out.h:31:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 void w_Endline(char* sent);
      ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
<builtin>: recipe for target 'query.o' failed
make: *** [query.o] Error 1

Comment: @Adarshjaya12 modify in_out.h function prototypes (remove const) in w_Endline if you are going to modify arguments

Comment: It's hard exactly to tell whats going on from your dense compiler errors, if you still have errors ask another question